# MaxPooling2D - Positional Argument follows keyword argument

Tags: python, keras, error-handling, max-pooling

My code is the following:

```
def create_model(input_shape = (224, 224, 3)):
    input_img = Input(shape=input_shape)
    model = efnB0_model (input_img)
    model = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3, 3), strides=2, 2)(model)

    backbone = model
```

When I try to run the code I get:

```
  File "<ipython-input-76-677f39f95f0d>", line 5
    model = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3, 3), strides=2, 2)(model)
                                                     ^
SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument
```

How should I amend my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Note: just by looking at it, cannot test)

```
strides=(2, 2)
```

(You are setting: `strides=2`,
and then passing another positional arg `2`)

Comment: That's it! Thank you!